# Switching between first person and third person(unity)

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have a project in unity.
How can change third person character to first person when enter on trigger?
I try this js code on player but don't work

```
 #pragma strict

var ThePlayer:GameObject;
var FirstPersonCam:GameObject;
var ThirdPersonCam:GameObject;
var check;

function Start () {
    ThirdPersonCam.gameObject.active=true;
    FirstPersonCam.gameObject.active=false;
    check=true;
}


function OnTriggerEnter( other :Collider)
{

    if(other.gameObject.name == "rubbishTrigger1")
    {
        if(check){
            FirstPersonCam.gameObject.active=true;
            ThirdPersonCam.gameObject.active=false;
        }
        else{
            FirstPersonCam.gameObject.active=false;
            ThirdPersonCam.gameObject.active=true;
        }
        check=!check;
    }

}
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: we need more information about your scene, how is your set up? What is happening right now?

Comment: I have  one player with 2 camera.I want switch camera  when i enter on trigger but no thing happen when i enter it.

Comment: Try to put a Debug.Log("entering on trigger enter"); right where the function starts and then put a Debug.Log("entering if statement"); right after the if has started.
This will let you know if it even registers the collision and if it does it will also let you know if the collision is with "rubbishTrigger1"

Comment: Also try with `gameObject.SetActive(true/false)` since active is obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.below code is true and it work good.

```
#pragma strict

var ThePlayer:GameObject;
var player:GameObject;
var FirstPersonCam:GameObject;
var ThirdPersonCam:GameObject;
var trigger:GameObject;


function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {

    if(FirstPersonCam.gameObject.active==false && ThirdPersonCam.gameObject.active==true){
        FirstPersonCam.gameObject.active=true;
        ThirdPersonCam.gameObject.active=false;
        player.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```